# Is it possible to create a RHEL 5.7 channel based on updated (5.9) RHEL channels in Satellite?

Tags: redhat, kickstart, provisioning, satellite, rhn

I would however like to kickstart new servers based on RHEL 5.7. Both official Red Hat channels in Satellite are already updated to RHEL 5.9 and RHEL 6.4 though.

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64) 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6 for 64-bit x86_64)
```

Can I create a frozen RHEL 5.7 channel based on the official Red Hat Channel that is already updated to the latest RHEL 5.9 on the Satellite server?

If not, how can I create a kickstartable RHEL 5.7 channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the 5.7 distribution as a kickstartable tree?
 If so, you can create a new kickstart profile for your RHEL5 channel, using the 5.7 distribution, and then make sure you don't update the box in %post

OR

have you looked into using the spacewalk-create-channel program? http://blog-zokahn.rhcloud.com/?p=219

Should be something like this:

```
spacewalk-create-channel -v 5 -s Server -u U7 -a x86_64 –d rhel5u7 –N “RHEL 5.7 channel”
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, spacewalk-clone-by-date caused me a lot of trouble with non-working channels, but spacewalk-create-channel works great. It does make me wonder why the newly created channel (rhel5u7) has only 2500 packages instead of 5500 that the clone-by-date channel has.

Comment: check the contents of the channels; my bet is that clone-by-date keeps all previous versions of the updated packages, while spacewalk-create-channel only takes those who came with the 5u7 release or something like that...

Comment: Yes, that seems correct, but how do I secure a channel created with spacewalk-create-channel? It seems RHEL 5.7 was released in 2011-07-21, so the channel hasn't had bug-fixes/security-updates since that date?

Comment: I would have channels constantly syncing from RHN and then on a regular basis I'd clone from there and move my systems to those. I'd do this on a regular basis and not care so much about minor releases.